# Photo App won't open after I downloaded OS X El Capitan V.10.11

Tags: macos, photos.app

Photo App won't open after I downloaded OS X El Capitan V.10.11. 
Response: "Photos must quit because the photo library has become unavailable or its data is corrupt."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass this, hold down the Option key as you open the Photos app. You will get a dialog box letting you choose other (i)Photo libraries, or open a new, blank library:

[image]

Comment: I only have the System Photo Library; so when I click on "Choose Library" I get the same response "Photos must quit..."

Comment: If you have a backup of this Library (Time Machine or other source) restore it to a location other than` /Users/<user_name>/Pictures` and use the Option key method to open it up. You should also open Photos app with the Option and Command keys down to attempt to repair the Library.

Comment: Thank you - thank you!Option/Command keys >> and my Photo Library is repaired - I hate to admit, but I would have lost 1/2 y. worth of photos.

Comment: Thank you. Opening Photo with command + option pressed works.ht library rebuilds and you are good to go.